# How to assign a property either lazily or normally in a conditional way

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I would like to assign one property either lazy or in a "normal way", but the problem is, that my value is always cast to "Any". I cannot use the "by" keyword, when I assign a property conditionally. Here is my current approach

```
abstract class IWorkerContract(private val isLazy: Boolean = false) {
    private val workRequest = if (isLazy) {
       // Type mismatch. Required: OneTimeWorkRequest Found: Lazy<OneTimeWorkRequest>
       lazy {
          OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<Worker>.build()
       }
    } else {
      OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<Worker>.build()
    }

}
```

### Edit Testing

```
abstract class IWorkerContract(private val isLazy: Boolean = false) {
    private val lazyMgr = ResettableLazyManager()

    private val workRequest by if (isLazy) {
        // Type 'TypeVariable(<TYPE-PARAMETER-FOR-IF-RESOLVE>)' has no method 'getValue(Test, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate
       resettableLazy(lazyMgr) {
          OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<Worker>.build()
       }
    } else {
      OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<Worker>.build()
    }
```

### Lazy Delegate

```
class ResettableLazy<PROPTYPE>(
    private val manager: ResettableLazyManager,
    private val init: () -> PROPTYPE,
) : Resettable {
    @Volatile
    private var lazyHolder = initBlock()

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): PROPTYPE = lazyHolder.value

    override fun reset() {
        lazyHolder = initBlock()
    }

    private fun initBlock(): Lazy<PROPTYPE> = lazy {
        manager.register(this)
        init()
    }
}

fun <PROPTYPE> resettableLazy(
    manager: ResettableLazyManager,
    init: () -> PROPTYPE,
): ResettableLazy<PROPTYPE> = ResettableLazy(manager, init)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split it up in 2 separate variables:

```
abstract class IWorkerContract(private val isLazy: Boolean = false) {
    private val lazyWorkRequest by lazy {
        OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<Worker>.build()
    }

    private val workRequest
        get() = when {
            isLazy -> lazyWorkRequest
            else -> OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<Worker>.build()
        }
}
```

Because of `get()`, `lazyWorkRequest` will not be initialised immediately but only when needed.

But more importantly: why is this behaviour needed, what is the harm of always using lazy?

Also, what is the intended purpose of `ResettableLazy`? It looks like all you want to have a `var` and this is the solution to solve the missing `getValue()` or `Type mismatch`. Is that correct?

It feels to me your question is too specific, too technical. Could you explain without using Kotlin what kind of behaviour you need?

Comment: ResettableLazy is a delegate whichs value is computed lazy but can be resetted

Answer (score 2):

> value is always cast to "Any"

Yes, because function `lazy { }` creates a new instance of `Lazy<OneTimeWorkRequest>`, not `OneTimeWorkRequest`, those types are incompatible. I don't understand your requirement exactly, but problem can be solved by providing a custom `Lazy` implementation, e.g.

```
class InitializedLazy<T>(override val value: T) : Lazy<T> {
    override fun isInitialized(): Boolean = true
}
```

Usage:

```
abstract class IWorkerContract(private val isLazy: Boolean = false) {
    private val workRequest by if (isLazy) {
        lazy { OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<Worker>().build() }
    } else {
        InitializedLazy(OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<Worker>().build())
    }
}
```

Comment: This does work, when I use the kotlin default "lazy". But when I use my own "resettableLazy", I get an error. I will add my code

Comment: Maybe you can add `isLazy` flag to  `resettableLazy` function and modify `initBlock()` like `/* register */ return if (isLazy) { lazy { init() } } else { InitializedLazy(init()) }`

Comment: @Andrew you aren’t following the advice of this answer. Both branches of the if/else must return a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

If you access your property in the constructor, if will be computed at instantiation time.

```
class Foo(val isLazy: Boolean){
    val bar: Int by lazy { computeValue() }
    init { if (!isLazy) bar }
}
```